# struts2jquery plugin alternative for sj:menu for plugins earlier then 3.5.0

Tags: struts2-jquery-plugin

I am looking for an alternative option for `<sj:menu>` . As my company is not ready to switch to 3.5.0 for a single component. I tried using the normal div to create the look, but css for hover and highlight is missing.

We currently use 3.3.0.

Comment: Add it? I mean, it just renders to normal HTML, which should be easy enough to duplicate. Is there a compelling *technical* reason not to update the plugin?

Comment: Every team in the company is provided with the plugin which is customised with some predefined company level changes. To get the latest we need to go through many approvals. So they are not ready to change it.@Dave

Comment: @DaveNewton you mean to say, take any Sj:menu convert into html and add it in code?